# Howto install python psutil on CentOS 6?

Tags: centos6, python, yum

```
#yum install python26 python26-devel python26-setuptools gcc
#easy_install psutil
[root@vps021 ~]# easy_install psutil
Searching for psutil
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/psutil/
Best match: psutil 3.2.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/psutil/psutil-3.2.2.tar.gz#md5=56df1727c9e26076a80da4c3f8f67976
Processing psutil-3.2.2.tar.gz
Running psutil-3.2.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-JLmzFu/psutil-3.2.2/egg-dist-tmp-1dna_f
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 18: 'recursive-include' expects <dir> <pattern1> <pattern2> ...
psutil/_psutil_linux.c:12:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

But python26-devel is installed. How is this possible? I'm not sure how to install python psutil on this system? (I'm also very unsatisfied by having only python version 2.6 but unfortunately, I'm tied to this system.)

Comment: python-psutil is in EPEL. But you really should untie yourself from this system.

Comment: I felt the same. Already asked the hosting company to reinstall ubuntu for me. They could only offer LTS 12.04 but I think that is still better.

Comment: It sounds like you should also find a better hosting company.

Comment: python 2.6 is the default in CentOS 6. python26 packages are available in CentOS 5 where 2.4 is the default so it sounds like your system is CentOS  5 not 6.  If it is you could install python26-psutil from EPEL.